# Solution of special equation with degree n

Tags: polynomials

I have the following equation with unknown $x$,

$$x^{n+1} - x^n + a = 0$$

where $x\in\mathbb{C}$ is possibly complex, $n\in\mathbb{N}$ is a positive integer, and $a\in\mathbb{R}_{>0}$ is positive.
Are there any formulas or methods to get solutions in closed form?
I have looked up solutions to equations where only maximum and one minus maximum degree of the unknown are present, but could not find anything of interest. I have also tried to think how one could possibly reduce the above to extraction of a complex root, but I did not manage to get to such a form.
Thanks!

Comment: Hi Luca, it is an habit in the Forum to present what you've already seek and find. Otherwise it is highly likely you will get downvote and no answer.

Comment: Hi @EDX, thanks for replying. Unfortunately I am not keen on this kind of problems and I am having issues even in searching for an answer. I have tried to look up solutions for generic equations with degree $n$ and also for special equations with only terms with degree $n$ and $n-1$, but could not find anything that looks interesting...

Comment: For $n\le 3$ there are indeed formulas, but not for polynmials of degree $\ge 5$. Say, if $a=1$, then  $x^{n+1}-x^n+1$ is irreducible over $\Bbb Q$, and the Galois group is $S_n$, so there is no solution by radicals.

Comment: Thanks you @DietrichBurde. I was indeed aware of formulas for "simple" ($n\le3$) cases but I hoped for some more general solution for greater $n$.

Comment: Using the first answer’s transformation and [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/418392/series-solution-for-general-trinomial) helps.

Answer (score 2):

Write $x = a^{1/(n+1)}/t$ and the equation becomes

$$ t^{n+1} - t/c + 1 = 0$$
where
$$ c = a^{1/(n+1)}$$
This has a root with an interesting series expansion in powers of $c$.
$$ t = c +  \sum_{k=1}^\infty  (n+1)^{k} \left(\prod_{m=0}^{k-1} \prod_{i=1}^n \frac{i+(n+1) m}{i+1+nm}\right) c^{1+(n+1)k} $$

Comment: You could simplify with this [Pochhammer symbol identity](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=prod%5B%28j%2B%28n%2B1%29m%29%2F%28j%2B1%2Bmn+%29%2C%7Bj%2C1%2Cn%7D%5D)

Answer (score 1):

Here are some approximations to the real roots. We split into cases depending on the sign of $n$.

**Case:** $n$ is odd. Then $f(x) = x^{n+1} - x^n + a$ has even degree. We have $\frac{df}{dx} = (n+1) x^n - n x^{n-1}$ and setting this equal to zero gives $x = 0, \frac{n}{n+1}$. The global minimum is at $x = \frac{n}{n+1}$ which gives

$$f \left( \frac{n}{n+1} \right) = - \frac{1}{n+1} \left( 1 - \frac{1}{n+1} \right)^n + a \approx - \frac{1}{en} + a$$

so there are no real roots unless $a$ is small, less than $\approx \frac{1}{en}$. If $a$ is this small then by the IVT there's a root to the left of $\frac{n}{n+1}$ and a root to the right. Write $x = 1 - \frac{y}{n}$, which gives

$$f(x) = - \frac{y}{n} \left( 1 - \frac{y}{n} \right)^n + a \approx a - \frac{y}{n} e^{-y}$$

and setting this equal to $0$ gives $ye^{-y} \approx an$ and hence $y \approx - W_0(-an)$ or $y \approx - W_{-1}(-an)$ where these are the two real branches of the [Lambert W function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function). So this gives two real roots

$$\boxed{ x \approx 1 + \frac{W_0(-an)}{n}, 1 + \frac{W_{-1}(-an)}{n} }.$$

**Case:** $n$ is even. Then $f(x)$ has odd degree. The above analysis continues to apply if $a$ is small enough and gives two positive roots, but now there is also a negative root by the IVT, which always exists. Writing $x = -\sqrt[n]{a} - \frac{y}{n}$ gives

$$f(x) = - (\sqrt[n]{a} + \frac{y}{n} + 1) a \left( 1 - \frac{y}{n \sqrt[n]{a}} \right)^n + a \approx - \left( 2 + \frac{\log a}{n} + \frac{y}{n} \right) a e^{- \frac{y}{1 + \frac{\log a}{n}}} + a$$

(where we approximate $\sqrt[n]{a} = \exp \left( \frac{\log a}{n} \right) \approx 1 + \frac{\log a}{n}$, only valid if $\log a$ is small compared to $n$), and setting this equal to $0$ gives

$$\frac{y}{1 + \frac{\log a}{n}} \approx \log \left( 2 + \frac{y + \log a}{n} \right) \approx \log 2 + \frac{y + \log a}{2n}$$

which looks complicated but basically gives $y \approx \log 2$ (with $O \left( \frac{1}{n} \right)$ error that could be solved for) and hence

$$\boxed{ x \approx - \sqrt[n]{a} - \log 2 }.$$

This also gives a rough approximation to the complex roots by taking $\sqrt[n]{a}$ to have its complex values but it's a worse approximation and I'm not sure how to cleanly find a better one.

Comment: One more elegant solution !

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici: all credit goes to the Lambert $W$ function and the trusty exponential approximation!

Comment: One of the problems with democracy is that we may disagree (joke) and, in this case, I do ! All credit goes to you. Cheers and thanks again for sharing so nice answers.

Comment: Would you look at the last sentence in my answer and at https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3117429/are-there-extensions-of-darboux-theorem-for-higher-order-methods which never received any answer . Thanks and cheers :-)

Answer (score 1):

Consider the case where $a$ is "large" and $n$ is even.

Let $x=-t$ and look for the zero of function
$$f(t)=t^{n+1}+t^n-a$$ The solution is such that
$$t_{\text{left}}=\left(\frac{a}{2}\right)^{\frac{1}{n+1}} < t <\left(\frac{a}{2}\right)^{\frac{1}{n}}=t_{\text{right}}$$

Over this range,
$$g(t)=\log(t^{n+1}+t^n)-\log(a)$$ is "close" to linearity and it second derivative is negative.

So, by [Darboux theorem](http://www.numdam.org/item/NAM_1869_2_8__17_0.pdf), starting iterations with $t_0= t_{\text{left}}$, Newton method will converge without any overshoot of the solution. The first iterate is
$$t_1=t_0-\frac {g(t_0)} {g('t_0)}$$

Trying with $a=123456789$, some results

$$\left(
\begin{array}{cccc}
n & t_0 & t_1 & \text{solution} \\
 2 & 395.210 & 486.267 &  497.601 \\
 4 & 36.1491 & 40.9892 &  41.3263 \\
 6 & 12.9696 & 14.1281 &  14.1809 \\
  8 & 7.33854 & 7.80578 &  7.82080 \\
 10 & 5.10771 & 5.35014 &  5.35592 \\
 12 & 3.97437 & 4.11991 &  4.12258 \\
 14 & 3.30648 & 3.40251 &  3.40390 \\
 16 & 2.87253 & 2.94020 &  2.94100 \\
 18 & 2.57055 & 2.62061 &  2.62109 \\
 20 & 2.34950 & 2.38792 &  2.38824 \\
\end{array}
\right)$$

Doing the same with Halley method and comparing
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cccc}
n & \text{Newton } t_1 & \text{Halley } t_1 & \text{solution} \\
 2 &  486.267 &  498.111 &  497.601   \\
 4 &  40.9892 &  41.3345 &  41.3263   \\
 6 &  14.1281 &  14.1817 &  14.1809   \\
  8 &  7.80578 &  7.82096 &  7.82080   \\
 10 &  5.35014 &  5.35596 &  5.35592    \\
 12 &  4.11991 &  4.12259 &  4.12258   \\
 14 &  3.40251 &  3.40391 &  3.40390   \\
 16 &  2.94020 &  2.94100 &  2.94100 \\
 18 &  2.62061 &  2.62109 &  2.62109   \\
 20 &  2.38792 &  2.38824 &  2.38824   \\
\end{array}
\right)$$

What could be interesting is to prove that the solution is bracketed by the first iterates of Newton and Halley method.